# Reading a text file in pandas with separator as linefeed (\n) and line terminator as two linefeeds (\n\n)

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, io

I have a text file of the form :

data.txt

```
2
8
4

3
1
9

6
5
7
```

How to read it into a pandas dataframe

```
  0 1 2
0 2 8 4
1 3 1 9
2 6 5 7
```

Comment: Is there always a gap after 3 elements?

Comment: No, there can be any number of elements, but same number of elements in each block

Comment: Okay, in that case, see my answer. You can make use of the fact that there are equal elements in every block for a very efficient solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is there a way to use 'sep' and 'lineterminator' keywords in pd.read_table to read this.

Comment: No chance, because `lineterminator` cannot be length greater than 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n',',').replace(',,','\n')

In [7]: pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), header=None)
Out[7]:
   0  1  2
0  2  8  4
1  3  1  9
2  6  5  7
```

Comment: This is such an amazing, out of the box answer. Love it!

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**
Much easier, if you know there are always `N` elements in a group - just load your data and reshape -

```
pd.DataFrame(np.loadtxt('data.txt').reshape(3, -1))

     0    1    2
0  2.0  8.0  4.0
1  3.0  1.0  9.0
2  6.0  5.0  7.0
```

To load integers, pass `dtype` to `loadtxt`  -

```
pd.DataFrame(np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=int).reshape(3, -1))

   0  1  2
0  2  8  4
1  3  1  9
2  6  5  7
```

---

**Option 2**
This is more general, will work when you cannot guarantee that there are always 3 numbers at a time. The idea here is to read in blank lines as `NaN`, and separate your data based on the presence of `NaN`s.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None,  skip_blank_lines=False)
df

      0
0   2.0
1   8.0
2   4.0
3   NaN
4   3.0
5   1.0
6   9.0
7   NaN
8   6.0
9   5.0
10  7.0

df_list = []
for _, g in df.groupby(df.isnull().cumsum().values.ravel()):
    df_list.append(g.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df

     0    1    2
0  2.0  8.0  4.0
1  3.0  1.0  9.0
2  6.0  5.0  7.0
```

Caveat - if your data *also* has NaNs, this will not separate properly.

Comment: Second solution really nice, (+1)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. Unfortunately, it's annoying to not really know whether it is a viable option or not, only because OP is unwilling to respond to questions/feedback in a timely fashion.

Comment: Ya, this kind of questions I dont like, because depends of data... :(

Answer (score 2):

Although this is definitely not the best way to handle it, we can do some processing ourselves. In case the values are integers, the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in f.read().split('\n\n')]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which produces:

```
>>> dataframe
   0  1  2
0  2  8  4
1  3  1  9
2  6  5  7
```

Comment: Is possible add alternative for general data, not only integers?